# How to await for module.exported function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

So I am learning Node and right now I am trying to test a function using Jest. The problem is this function:

*oldButtonFunc.js*

```
module.exports = {
func: function (oldButton) {
    import("./newButton.js")
        .then(function(module) {
            oldButton.innerHTML = "new button was appended"
            const appendedButton = module.default;
            oldButton.parentNode.appendChild(appendedButton)
            console.log(oldButton+' clicked')

            return oldButton
        });
    }
}
```

This test: *oldButtonFunc.test.js*

```
var mockOldButton = document.getElementById('oldButton')
        var myButton

        mockOldButton.onclick = function () {
            import('./oldButtonFunc').then(function (module) {
                myButton = module.func(oldButton)       //how to await it???
            })
        }

        mockOldButton.click()

        expect(myButton.innerHTML).toEqual("new button was appended")
```

gives the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined**

If it's relevant - i'm using webpack.

Comment: Just put this line `expect(myButton.innerHTML).toEqual("new button was appended")` after the `myButton = ...` line

Comment: same error... :(

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out:

1. I need to enable async/await in Babel (i use Babel 7) - I required appropriate modules
2. I used jest's done() function to be sure to exit at particular point in code

Now my testing code looks like the following:

```
require("core-js/stable")
require("regenerator-runtime/runtime")

describe("button specification", () => {
    it('new button is appended to DOM after click on old button',
        async (done) => {

        document.body.innerHTML =
            '<span>siemanko</span>' +
            '<div class="my-div">' +
                '<div>' +
                    'some content' +
                '</div>' +
                '<button id="oldButton">' +
                    'lazily append new button' +
                '</button>'
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="img-wrapper">' +
                '<img id="img" />' +
            '</div>';

        var mockOldButton = document.getElementById('oldButton')

        mockOldButton.onclick = function () {
            var myFunction = require('../js/oldButtonFunc').func
            myFunction(mockOldButton)
        }

        await mockOldButton.click()
        done()

        expect(myButton.innerHTML).toEqual("new button was appended")
    })
})
```